# convert list to table and bind to gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a listitem that have a field contain Name and creation date

```
        Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
            files.Add(New ListItem(File.GetCreationTime(filePath), filePath))
        Next
        GridView2.DataSource = files
        GridView2.DataBind()
```

bind to boundfield

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Report Name" />
```

first files.add is `name` and second is `Creation date` it's show just one column how can I convert them to 2 column

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Report Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="???" HeaderText="Creation Date" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DataTable` here instead of `ListItem` as you may need to bind more than two columns.

*Creating DataTable*

```
Function GetTable() As DataTable
{
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
     Dim table As New DataTable
     table.Columns.Add("FileName");
     table.Columns.Add("FileCreationTime");
     For Each filePath As String In filePaths
        table.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath), File.GetCreationTime(filePath).ToString())
     Next   
    return table;
}
```

*Assigning DataTable to GridView DataSource*

```
GridView2.DataSource = GetTable()
GridView2.DataBind()
```

*Binding DataTable columns with Controls*

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Report Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileCreationTime" HeaderText="Creation Date" />
```

Comment: looks like your code will work, Can you convert to Vb.Net Please ? I try to use a website to convert but it's error on Typedecl

Comment: I already tried that but I think I missed the Table declaration. Can you try it and let me know if there is still something to be changed. Your suggestion for converting to VB.net would be a plus!

Comment: ok i use it's as Function like this `Function GetTable() As DataTable` replace `static DataTable GetTable()` and your code is work like a charm !